# Order 3rd party spring filters at bean creation time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know filters can be annotated with @Order() but if the filters are all included from different 3rd party libraries can I order them when I create the bean?

```
@Bean(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) // Illegal!!!, just an example
SomeFilter someFilter() {
   // this runs before someOtherFilter
   return new SomeFilter();
}

@Bean(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) // Illegal!!!, just an example
SomeOtherFilter someOtherFilter() {
   // this runs after someFilter
   return new SomeOtherFilter();
}
```

Comment: The code above - is it a putative part of a configuration class?

Comment: It's an example but sure, it must be in a configration class. It's an illegal example though, @bean doesn't take an int as default parameter and no ordering at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot add the @Order annotation on filters, you can still use [FilterRegistrationBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html) like this:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilter()
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        SomeFilter filter = new SomeFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/bla/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to know all the filters that gets declared? I really want to order just a few of them and don't have to care about the rest.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand The above example deals **only** with SomeFilter instance. You can ignore anything else as you please!!